# Reading BLE telegrams on COM ports

Tags: serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read BLE telegrams sent to a usb plugged reciever to my PC.
I am using a serial port reader ( used putty at first then tryed some other software from the net). However, I get nothing, not data at all sent; not from my sender not even any telegram from may be other unknowm devices that may be there advertising.
I have run mode on command line to give me information and it shows that my com port has a baudrate of 1200.
I must say this value was not fix it goes from 1200 to 57600. 
I know that my data is sent at a baudrate of 57600: so I'm thinking may be the problem is that the baudrates being different it can't get the data but then it should come to a time where I can see at least some insignificant data of incomplete telegram. I have also tried to change the baudrate on the serial com port reader but same result nothing at all.
My question is what might be the problem and how can I fix it ? in other words having a BLE reciever and tranciever how can I read the telegrams on COM ports